# SAPUI5, Refresh subentities after main entity deletion

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I faced an issue for which I am still looking for solution.

I have main entity, like Package, and then subentity, like PackageGoods.
Then there is an option to delete a Package and create new one.
Once Package is deleted, backend deletes entry with such id, and also all PackageGoods for it.
The new created Package gets same id, as the deleted one had.

Problem:
If I delete old package with some goods, and then create new one in same session, 
the binding for goods still shows me the old entities, deleted in backend.

I tried calling odatamodel v2. refresh, with bForceUpdate = true and bRemoveData = true, issue still stays the same.

How did you fixed it if you faced with it?

Comment: Oh geez, entries with the same key are generally cached internally in the odata models :O can you do something to make the key unique like add the created date as a second key field?

Comment: I could have a workaround loop over of aggregation binding, but unfortunately this would be a big change, as now deletion is done centrally for all type of objects, even those who never could have this aggregation).